# How to call a method in another class of the same package?

Tags: java, methods

How to call a method, which is in another class of same package in Java?
What I know is, using an object we can call a method from a different class.
Is there any other way to call a method of different class?

Comment: edit: link is no longer valid - changed the link to oracle java tutorial. [Java Static Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 12):

Create an instance of Class B:

```
B b=new B();
b.method();
```

or define an static method in Class B:

```
class B
{
 static void staticMethod();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
B.staticMethod();
```

Answer (score 4):

Methods are *object methods* or *class methods*.

**Object methods:** it applies over an object. You have to use an instance:

```
instance.method(args...);
```

**Class methods:** it applies over a class. It doesn't have an implicit instance. You have to use the class itself. It's more like procedural programming.

```
ClassWithStaticMethod.method(args...);
```

**Reflection**

With reflection you have an API to programmatically access methods, be they object or class methods.

Instance methods: `methodRef.invoke(instance, args...);`
Class methods: `methodRef.invoke(null, args...);`

Answer (score 3):

If you define the method as static you can use it without instantiating the class first, but then you also dont have the object variables available for use.

```
public class Foo {
   public static String Bar() {
      return "bla";
   }
}
```

In that case you could call it with `Foo.Bar()`.

Answer (score 3):

*From the Notes of Fred Swartz (fredosaurus)* :

There are two types of methods.

- **Instance methods** are associated with an object and use the instance variables of that object. This is the default.
- **Static methods** use no instance variables of any object of the class they are defined in. If you define a method to be static, you will be given a rude message by the compiler if you try to access any instance variables. You can access static variables, but except for constants, this is unusual. Static methods typically take all they data from parameters and compute something from those parameters, with no reference to variables. This is typical of methods which do some kind of generic calculation. A good example of this are the many utility methods in the predefined `Math` class.

## Qualifying a static call

From outside the defining class, an instance method is called by prefixing it with an object, which is then passed as an implicit parameter to the instance method, eg, `inputTF.setText("");`

A static method is called by prefixing it with a class name, eg, `Math.max(i,j);`. Curiously, it can also be qualified with an object, which will be ignored, but the class of the object will be used.

## Example

Here is a typical static method:

```
class MyUtils {
    . . .
    //================================================= mean
    public static double mean(int[] p) {
        int sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
        for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
            sum += p[i];
        }
        return ((double)sum) / p.length;
    }//endmethod mean
    . . .
}
```

The only data this method uses or changes is from parameters (or local variables of course).

## Why declare a method `static`

The above `mean()` method would work just as well if it wasn't declared static, as long as it was called from within the same class. If called from outside the class and it wasn't declared static, it would have to be qualified (uselessly) with an object. Even when used within the class, there are good reasons to define a method as static when it could be.

- **Documentation.** Anyone seeing that a method is static will know how to call it (see below). Similarly, any programmer looking at the code will know that a static method can't interact with instance variables, which makes reading and debugging easier.
- **Efficiency.** A compiler will usually produce slightly more efficient code because no implicit object parameter has to be passed to the method.

## Calling static methods

*There are two cases.*

**Called from within the same class**

Just write the static method name. Eg:

```
// Called from inside the MyUtils class
double avgAtt = mean(attendance);
```

**Called from outside the class**

If a method (static or instance) is called from another class, something must be given before the method name to specify the class where the method is defined. For instance methods, this is the object that the method will access. For static methods, the class name should be specified. Eg:

```
// Called from outside the MyUtils class.
double avgAtt = MyUtils.mean(attendance);
```

If an object is specified before it, the object value will be ignored and the the class of the object will be used.

## Accessing static variables

Altho a `static` method can't access instance variables, it can access `static` variables. A common use of static variables is to define "constants". Examples from the Java library are `Math.PI` or `Color.RED`. They are qualified with the class name, so you know they are `static`. Any method, `static` or not, can access `static` variables. Instance variables can be accessed only by instance methods.

## Alternate Call

What's a little peculiar, and not recommended, is that an object of a class may be used instead of the class name to access static methods. This is bad because it creates the impression that some instance variables in the object are used, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static method, you can call it by using the class name in place of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a static method or use the other class as a member of your class calling the function in the constructor.

```
public class aClass {
      private SomeOtherClass oc;
      public class aClass( SomeOtherClass otherClass) {
         oc = otherClass;
      }

      public callOtherClassMethod() {
         oc.otherClassMethod();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this format:

`classmehodisin.methodname();`

For example:

`MyClass1.clearscreen();`

I hope this helped.`
Note:The method must be static.

Answer (score -1):

By calling method

```
public class a 
{
    void sum(int i,int k)
    {
        System.out.println("THe sum of the number="+(i+k));
    }
}
class b
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        a vc=new a();
        vc.sum(10 , 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: By declaring an instance of the class, in the example is named ´vc´ and calling the method of the instance.