# Why we do not create object for static method in java?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Sometimes we call `className.methodName()` without creating object for it, I mean without using syntax as `className objectName = new constructor()` and then call as `object.methodName()`

1. When to use `className.methodName()`?
2. When to call method using object as `object.methodName()`?

Explanation of above two cases with example will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean a `static` method. Consider having a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Google "java static methods"

Comment: Have you tried at least once to search on Google about your question? If you had tried it then you would have saved your time to type the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713643/how-to-call-a-method-in-java)

Comment: Google: [calling a method in java](https://www.google.com/search?q=calling+a+method+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: There are frameworks like Ofbiz that heavily use static method. Other like spring do not use them that much. Any answer given will be a mix of expertise and sheer opinion.

Comment: The question is valuable for me.  I am not a beginner of Java. But suddenly, I felt I am not clear the goodness of static creating instance method compared with constructors.  Alexey Nikitenko 's answer help me to some degreee. haha.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is a `static` method.

Assume that I have this :

```
public class A {

    public static void foo(){
        System.out.println("Hooray! I work!");
    }

}
```

You can now do this anywhere else in any other class :

```
A.foo();
```

This is because the method is static, which means that it can be called on by the CLASS.
This means that it doesn't require an instance of that class in order for the method to be called.

However, even though it isn't required, you can still do this :

```
A a = new A();
a.foo();
```

But since the method `foo()` is static, instantiating an object `A` is not required in order to run the `foo()` method.

Answer (score 2):

**First.** When you're create at least one static method of a class, you can use this method without creating an instance of class. This is useful, for example, for the creation of methods with independent logic. For example:

```
 public class Checker {
        public static Boolean month(int value) {
            return (value >= 1 && value <= 12);
        }
    }
```

You need check correct value of month many times. But what to do each time to create the object. It is much effective to use a static method.

**Second.** When you create the object, the object is stored in the memory and you get a link to it. Then the object can be used for example to save at the list.
Method at this object is specific. You can save class data and do specific operation with member of this class. For example:

```
List<Animals> animalsList = new ArrayList<>();
Animal animal = new Animal("dog");
int legs = animal.getCountLegs(); // specific function for object
animalList.add(animal); //save if you need
// use list of object
```

Answer (score 0):

For every class, we have a Object called as *class object* which is `YourClass.class` object. *static methods* are invoked based on meta-data on those objects. For *instances* of a class, methods are invoked on the actual instances. Both *static* and *non-static* methods are present on method area.

Comment: @immibis - I meant to say that static methods are loaded based on meta-data derived from those objects

Answer (score 0):

There is no different between 1 and 2 point, because in during compilation compiler makes ClassName.staticMethod() instead of instance.staticMethod().

Answer (score 0):

Static methods in java belong to the class (not an instance of it). They use no instance variables and will usually take input from the parameters, perform actions on it, then return some result. Instances methods are associated with objects and, as the name implies, can use instance variables.