# Open PDF file with default browser in java

Tags: java

Snippet of the code

```
    public class AnyPlatformAppPDF {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {

            File pdfFile = new File("c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\css\\Praveen_Profile.pdf");
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("File is not exists!");
            }

            System.out.println("Done");

          } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }

        }

        public static void openWebpage(java.net.URI uri) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
            if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                try {
                    desktop.browse(uri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I tried this code to open pdf file in browser but it doesn't open the pdf file. I am using Java to do so.
How can I fix this?

Comment: and then.. what happenned?

Comment: program runs successfully but it opens in adobe reader i need to open it by browser.

Comment: You haven't used the `openWebPage` method anyway.

Comment: i am new to java just started i haven't used.

Comment: use it and then update if its doesn't work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713643/how-to-call-a-method-in-java If that can help you.

Comment: sure nullpointer

Comment: Tried but didn't worked.

Comment: Please update the question what you've tried and what didn't work there.

Comment: i tried to convert a local pdf file to url (path to url ) but didn't worked.

Comment: I meant update the question by Editing it and with the code used and what didn't work in terms of error you faced or some expected /unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Using process builder may solve your problem;

//Windows

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "explorer c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\css\\Praveen_Profile.pdf");
```

//Linux

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "sensible-browser c:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\css\\Praveen_Profile.pdf");
```

//

```
processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: How to implement this process builder to above program Alican Beydemir.

Comment: First clear all of the "Desktop" related logics then put an "if else" check for Operating System consistency https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-detect-os-in-java-systemgetpropertyosname/ after that create appropriate processbuilder inside "if else" scope use start method in try catch...