# Forming Mail Body in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Currently working on a project where my `DataRetrival` class is to be set in the java Mail API body.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
public class DataRetrival {

    public List<Employee> javaData() {
        DatabaseConnect dc = new DatabaseConnect();
        Connection con;

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = dc.connect();
            String query ="SELECT * FROM employee";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

               while (rs.next())
                  {

                  Employee emp = new Employee();
                   emp.setID(rs.getInt("ID"));
                   emp.setEmployee_Number(rs.getString("Employee_Number"));
                   emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                   emp.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
                   emp.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
                   emp.setPdfName(rs.getString("PdfName"));
                   emp.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("Sup_EmailAddress")); 
                   employees.add(emp);


                   String employeeNumber = rs.getString("Employee_Number");
                   System.out.println(employeeNumber);

                  }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

Created new instance like this.

```
DataRetrival dtr = new DataRetrival();
```

from this new instance or any other method, I want to fill the field of **InterenetAddress.parse** field which contains another class called **JavaMail** with the above field **EmailAddress** mentioned in  code segment;

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Want get called Email_Adress));
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to call the `javaData()` method? Are you asking how to loop over the `Employee` objects returned by that method? Are you asking how to call the `getEmailAddress()` method on such an `Employee` object? What *specifically* is stopping you? --- [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: *FYI:* Your code is never closing any of the JDBC objects returned, so you are leaking resources like crazy. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to correctly close `ResultSet`, `Statement`, and `Connection` objects.

Comment: Sir, i want to call javaData() and get getEmailAddress to another class.

Comment: @Andreas. um very new to the programming. if i know all why i waste resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043270/forming-mail-body-in-javamail?noredirect=1#comment91037607_52043270):

> i want to call javaData() and get getEmailAddress to another class

To call `javaData()`:

```
DataRetrival dtr = new DataRetrival();
List<Employee> employees = dtr.javaData();
```

To get `getEmailAddress`:

```
for (Employee employee : employees) {
    String emailAddress = employee.getEmailAddress();
    // use value here
}
```

Both of the above constructs are core Java features, so I'd suggest you (re)read your Java guide on [how to do method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3713643/5221149) and [how to iterate a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18410035/5221149).

Comment: It works, thanks, i know that i want to improve my self very much. i wanna ask one thing. if i iterate list as you are saying how can i set the String emailAddress into InternetAddress.parse(String))

Comment: @Anushkalakmal I don't understand your question. Are you truly asking me how to pass a parameter on a method call? You're doing it many times in the `javaData()` method implementation.

Comment: @Anushkalakmal It seems that the task you're trying to do is beyond your current level of programming. I suggest you go back and try working with simpler tasks until your proficiency improves. Go through a Java tutorial to learn how method calls work, and how to pass parameters to method. StackOverflow is not a teaching site, and not a site for having other people write your code for you. If you don't understand the very basics, working with JDBC is way beyond where you should be at this point.

Comment: i understand what you are saying. thanks for the help. i found a new job and they gave me that project. they also says that you put into deep water.so somehow i have to manage.